# How to use instance of API from Main Activity in Fragments?

Tags: java, api, android-fragments, android-activity

If i create an instance of an API in Main Activity, can i use it in fragments so i don't need to create that instance again? Example:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCombatActivity {

CustomApi customApi;

@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        customApi = new CustomApi(this, key);

    }

}
```

How can i access this customApi instance in fragments created by the MainActivity without creating an instance of this CustomApi again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fragment has access to its `Activity`, so you can do something like this in your `Fragement`:

```
CustomApi customApi = ((MainActivity) getActivity()).customApi;
customApi.method1(...);
```

This is a bit brute force, but is a simple and easy way to do the job. This assumes that your `Fragment` is only used by a single `Activity`. If your `Fragment` is used by multiple activities, you could define an `Interface` and have all parent activities implement that interface and access the `customApi` that way.

A cleaner, more Android-approved, more professional approach would be to use a `ViewModel`. The `ViewModel` is shared by the `Activity` and all of its `Fragment`s and you could manage the custom API reference in the `ViewModel`. For some examples of how to use `ViewModel` to communicate between `Activity` and `Fragment`, you can look here:

https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/communicate

Comment: I ended up using brute force.I only got one activity and multiple fragments. The professional approach is tempting i must say, but brute force is just simpler. I guess if you do want to change parameters of that instance inside fragments than a View Model is better.